# Perl XML::LibXML replace text

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

Simple xml file `cr.xml`

```
<book_reviewers>
    <results>
        <reviewer>
            <name>Anne</name>
            <profession>Catfish wrangler</profession>
        </reviewer>
        <reviewer>
            <name>Bob</name>
            <profession>Beer taster</profession>
        </reviewer>
        <reviewer>
            <name>Charlie</name>
            <profession>Gardener</profession>
        </reviewer>
    </results>
</book_reviewers>
```

I want to loop through each reviewer and replace the name with a new one

I am not trying to use both these methods, but going by other posts in the form both of these should work but I keep getting errors:

`Can't locate object method "setData"`

`Can't locate object method "removeChildNodes`

`Can't locate object method "appendText"`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $critics_file = "cr.xml";
my $parser = new XML::LibXML;   


print "Couldn't retrieve review details\n" 
    unless my $book_reviews  = $parser->parse_file($reviews_file);


foreach my $critics ($critic_details->findnodes('/book_reviewers/results/reviewer')) {

    my $value = $critics->findvalue('name');    #returns the correct name
    $value->removeChildNodes();
    $value->appendText('new_name');

     ##ONLY EITHER THE ABOVE METHOD OR THE ONE BELOW - NOT BOTH

    my $node  = $critics->findnodes('.//name.text()');#returns the correct name
    $node->setData('new_name');


}
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Cheers

Comment: What happens if you don't find a value or a node???

Comment: Your program doesn't compile. Please show the code that is giving the results that you describe

Comment: Not even the XML is valid. This is a very careless question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Trying to get you into TIMTOWTDI, here is another example with more compact code:

You can find all the `<name>…</name>` elements directly, and you can iterate over them immediately, using the 'default' variable `$_`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use utf8;

use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = "cr.xml";

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $critic_details = $parser->parse_file("$filename") or die;

my $new_name = "new_name";

# find ALL the <book_reviewers><results><reviewers><name> nodes
foreach ($critic_details
  ->findnodes("book_reviewers/results/reviewer/name")
) {
  $_->removeChildNodes();
  $_->appendText($new_name);
}

use XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint;
my $pretty = XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint->new(
  indent_string =>' ' x4,
  element       => {
    compact       => [qw| name profession |],
    }
  );
$pretty->pretty_print($critic_details);

print $critic_details->toString;

__END__
```

enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

#### Solution using [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML)

The following directly accesses the [Text Node](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Text) to simply and easily change the enclosed text:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( IO => \*DATA );

for my $text ( $doc->findnodes('//reviewer/name/text()') ) {
    $text->setData('new_name');
}

print $doc->toString;

__DATA__
<book_reviewers>
    <results>
        <reviewer>
            <name>Anne</name>
            <profession>Catfish wrangler</profession>
        </reviewer>
        <reviewer>
            <name>Bob</name>
            <profession>Beer taster</profession>
        </reviewer>
        <reviewer>
            <name>Charlie</name>
            <profession>Gardener</profession>
        </reviewer>
    </results>
</book_reviewers>
```

#### Solution using [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig)

Takes the name of each reviewer and just reverses them:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $t= XML::Twig->new( 
    twig_handlers => {
        q{//reviewer/name} => sub { $_->set_text(scalar reverse $_->text()) },
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
);
$t->parse( do { local $/; <DATA> } );
$t->print;

__DATA__
<book_reviewers>
    <results>
        <reviewer>
            <name>Anne</name>
            <profession>Catfish wrangler</profession>
        </reviewer>
        <reviewer>
            <name>Bob</name>
            <profession>Beer taster</profession>
        </reviewer>
        <reviewer>
            <name>Charlie</name>
            <profession>Gardener</profession>
        </reviewer>
    </results>
</book_reviewers>
```

Outputs:

```
<book_reviewers>
  <results>
    <reviewer>
      <name>ennA</name>
      <profession>Catfish wrangler</profession>
    </reviewer>
    <reviewer>
      <name>boB</name>
      <profession>Beer taster</profession>
    </reviewer>
    <reviewer>
      <name>eilrahC</name>
      <profession>Gardener</profession>
    </reviewer>
  </results>
</book_reviewers>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this call

```
my $value = $critics->findvalue('name')
```

returns the string content of the `name` element, and you are trying to treat it as an `XML::LibXML::Element` object.

Just change the method call to

```
my ($value) = $critics->findnodes('name')
```

and all should be well.

Here is a working version of your program.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $reviews_file = 'cr.xml';
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;

my $doc = $parser->parse_file($reviews_file) or die "Couldn't parse book reviewers\n";

for my $reviewer ($doc->findnodes('/book_reviewers/results/reviewer')) {
  my ($name) = $reviewer->findnodes('name');
  $name->removeChildNodes;
  $name->appendText('new_name');  
}

print $doc->toString;
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book_reviewers>
    <results>
        <reviewer>
            <name>new_name</name>
            <profession>Catfish wrangler</profession>
        </reviewer>
        <reviewer>
            <name>new_name</name>
            <profession>Beer taster</profession>
        </reviewer>
        <reviewer>
            <name>new_name</name>
            <profession>Gardener</profession>
        </reviewer>
    </results>
</book_reviewers>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $value = $critics->findvalue('name');    #returns the correct name
$value->removeChildNodes();
$value->appendText('new_name');
```

`$value` is a simple scalar that holds the text of the found xml-element `<name>…</name>`. You can not call any of those methods on a 'string', can you?

Comment: Sorry Borodin - there can be only one (ticked answer) but they are both great - and seeing both ways makes it so much easier understand - I need to go feed my family but then I will come back and give it a go - thanks again

Comment: @KerynDrake: You must be ruthless! I gave up chasing reputation points a long time ago as I found it interfered with writing good and appropriate answers. The main thing you should consider is which of the answers is most likely to be useful to someone else that has a similar problem and has found your question in a search.

Comment: @KerynDrake one thing you might have noticed, those that have a passion for Perl, that participate or are community-members, we love to help each other out with troubles. Borodin is no exception. Oh, and you might consider joining IRC and the local perl-monger groups, where you can find more people interested in Perl.